# can't get GET variables

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to get the values from GET.  I've been using:

```
Request.QueryString["$random_var"]
```

with success for a little while now.  Suddenly, this code:

```
bool preview = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["previewtheme"]));
```

Produces this error:

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.UserControl.Request.get'
```

I am using the following:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
```

Any ideas of what is keeping asp.net from doing this simple task?

Comment: Post more code. The whole page minus unrelated details if possible

Comment: Also, is there a control on your page named 'Request'? I think that's confusing it with the Page.Request property.

Comment: I would post more of the code, however its not mine.  But I think I figured it out.  The bool was posted as a global var for the class I am coding.  If I put that bool in a function instead, it works.  BTW, thanks for fixing the using code up above :)

Comment: Sounds like you should've used PHP. :)